# Why isn't IIS 7 returning JSON faults? Works on *my* machine

Tags: .net, json, wcf, iis, .net-4.0

I am following the principles from the following blog post and I am getting the behavior that I expect when I debug my WCF Service using the Visual Studio 2010's built in web server.

http://zamd.net/2008/07/08/error-handling-with-webhttpbinding-for-ajaxjson/

When my application throws a FaultException(), I can see the JSON representation of that fault on my local machine.  The application also returns the appropriate HttpStatusCode (in this case, 401 Unauthorized), which is the desired behavior.

```
{"Code":"UserNotLoggedInFault","DisplayText":"You must be logged in to access this resource.","InternalText":"User is not logged in"}
```

When I deploy my application to IIS 7.0 though, I get the correct HttpStatusCode, but the html returned is the generic text that is associated with the status code:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Because this is working locally, I assume that the issue is an IIS configuration setting.  I have already removed the IIS: Error Pages values that were intercepting error statuses (it used to return formatted HTML from %SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr\\401.htm)

Does anyone know what IIS settings I need to change to allow the JSON response to pass through when an HTTP Status outside of the 200 range is returned?  ...or perhaps there is something else I need to do?

---

**UPDATE #1**

This only appears to be happening when my application throws a FaultException that also sets the HttpStatusCode to Unauthorized (401).  If my application returns a status code of 404 Not Found, then the JSON is returned properly.

The question still stands, but I suppose it only applies to returning a 401 Unauthorized status code.

Here are some screenshots of the response as captured by Charles Web Proxy

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A11g3.jpg

Here is what it looks like when I hit my local machine

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njfl5.jpg

---

**UPDATE #2**

So this does *not* happen if I remote desktop into the server and hit the site via localhost.  When I hit my URL that requires authentication, I get the proper JSON object returned.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV4Cr.png

So does that mean that IIS treats 401 status code differently and that non-authenticated users are shielded from the proper response?

Comment: What is your local hosting - IIS or IIS Express? Are you able to become responses from other sites on server?

Comment: Locally, I am running WebDev.WebServer40.exe.  On my Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 server, I can POST and GET JSON objects and everything works great, except when I throw a FaultException.  When I throw it locally, I get the JSON structure.  When I throw it on my Windows Server/IIS box, I get the "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." response.

Comment: And what about other web apps, or services from server. Are you able to make successful HTTP calls to something else from server?

Comment: Yes, everything else on that machine is working fine.

Comment: Strange, try to compare settings of similar application working application or service and find differences. Something should be. But exactly what is unclear to me from information I have.

Answer (score 11):

We found a setting in IIS "Error pages" configuration that fixes that behavior.

You need to set the error responses to "Detailed Errors", the default is "Detail errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests". You can set it in your website or server-wide.

It seems that the feature decides to show the custom error page for 401 instead of giving more detail to an unauthorized client.

Just make sure that your service error handling shields the exception, otherwise the client can see a stacktrace.

Comment: This solved a similar issue for me.  I was trying to return a status of 400 with some descriptive json for invalid requests.  On my machine it worked great, on the server, I'd get the IIS html response.  @Hector - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The "You do not have permission" is being generated by the browser. I suppose you are viewing the response to the request in a browser; I'm guessing IE.

IE is generating that "friendly" page for you, given the 401 response.  IE is not a json client, and it thinks the caller is a human (almost always correct).  So it is displaying a human-friendly page.

If you tickle that URL with Fiddler, or with wget.exe or some other non-browser tool, you will see the correct output with the 401 status code and the json response.

Not sure what happens on other browsers.

For more on the "friendly" error pages in IE, including how to turn them off, see [this article from Eric Lawrence (author of Fiddler)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/08/19/http-error-pages-in-internet-explorer.aspx).

Comment: It is *not* being generated by the browser.  I am using Charles as a web proxy and the response text shows "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Comment: Here are some screenshots of the Charles Web Proxy response http://imgur.com/a/MkRRI

Comment: I don't know how charles works.  Could you use Fiddler?  (LIke charles only it does not depend on Java).   What about wget? Curl?   even a jscript using XmlHttpRequest?  I would double-check what Charles is telling you.  Does your application actually see the "You do not have permission..." message?  Or are you seeing that only in the diagnostic tools you are using.  Still seems like that message is being injected by something in the tool chain, not by IIS.

Comment: Charles is a web proxy just like Fiddler.  Please rest assured that I am talking about the actual response, not some canned response that the browser/client is trying to present to me.  I am seeing exact the same message regardless of browser or web proxy.

Comment: hmm, ok.  Well maybe it's IIS that's inserting the "friendly" response. Try this: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/267/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis/